# Is there any Exception super-class, like Throwable of Java Exception, in Python?

Tags: python, exception, hierarchy

What is the super-class of `Exception` in Python? Please provide me the Python exception hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

`Exception`'s base class:

```
>>> Exception.__bases__
(BaseException,)
```

[Exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) from the docs confirms that it is a base class for all exceptions:

```
BaseException
 +-- SystemExit
 +-- KeyboardInterrupt
 +-- GeneratorExit
 +-- Exception
      +-- StopIteration
      +-- ArithmeticError
      |    +-- FloatingPointError
...
```

The syntax to catch all exceptions is:

```
try:
    raise anything
except: 
    pass
```

NOTE: use it very very sparingly e.g., you could use it in a `__del__` method during cleanup when the world might be half-destroyed and there is no other alternative.

Python 2 allows to raise exceptions that are not derived from `BaseException`:

```
>>> raise 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not int
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> raise A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.A: <__main__.A instance at 0x7f66756faa28>
```

It is fixed in Python 3 that enforces the rule:

```
>>> raise 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

Comment: It seems amazing to me that `except:` was never made a SyntaxError, it doesn't seem worthy of the abbreviation! (vs `except BaseException:`). I guess it's for convenience and backwards compat in scripts (though I bet most of the time they meant `except Exception:`).

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`BaseException`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException).

User defined exception types should subclass `Exception`.

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).